# questions about expires header

Tags: http, caching, glassfish

1. if there is no expires http header set in the response , what does it mean for browsers?
2. In Glassfish v3, how to configure expires header for static resources that have been deployed under docroot not as a war file?
3. I noticed that Glassfish seems to set ETag header by default. Is that true?
   The ultimate goal I want to achieve here is to set a far future expires header but be able to tell browsers "there is new stuff" whenever new version of css, js, image files are deployed.

Thanks so much for any advices.

Comment: That is 3 questions,  not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `expires` not provided in header of the server response, see §14.21 here:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Even when provided, `expires` is overriden by the `max-age` directive, thus if `expires` is not provided `max-age` is used. If none are provided, then see §13.2.4 here:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.4
Basically it says the client can set cache for an undetermined period of time, and not consistently.

**To solve your problem**, you may say your static elements never expire, and add an expire time to the included elements of a HTML doc. To do that, see here:
http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-far-future-expires-headers-to-your-wordpress-site-1533

Quoted: "To add expires header to the image, CSS, javascript files add the following to your `.htaccess` file

Expire Header

```
> <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
> </FilesMatch>
```

or Expire images header

```
> ExpiresActive On 
> ExpiresDefault A0
> ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
```

[...]
Keep in mind that when you use expires header the files are cached in the browser until it expires so do not use this on files that changes frequently. If you change/update a file that has a far future expiry (eg. CSS or javascript files) then you should rename that file and use the renamed version so the browser doesn’t fetch the old file."

Answer (score 5):

Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx for background.

1. If you don't specify freshness, some browsers will check every time. Some will check once-per-session. Most latest version browsers will try to calculate a heuristic expiration of 10% of the time since the Last-Modified date, if provided. If not, they'll check every time or once per session.
2. No idea.
3. That's not how HTTP expiration works-- the browser won't magically "know" that new content appeared on the server (how could it?). If you want to change content that's cached on the client, you will need to change your URLs so that the old cached content is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your second question is concerned, i find this resource interesting:

http://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish

The solution presented there is not just configuration but requires a Filter to be implemented and used.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether or not the Expires header is set, the actual action performed is implementation-dependent. It's only a suggestion to the browser, and any given version of any given browser can ignore it at will.

As for question 3, you could append a query string that is either a version number, last modified date (if your stylesheet or javascript are changing more than once per day, you're not using testing or staging properly), or current checksum of the file. For example, instead of `site.css`, you could use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css?lastmodified=20110605">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="site.css?sha1sum=da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but it's easier to format output in an answer than in a comment.

1. If there is no "expires" header and no other caching headers, the browser should not cache the
   content. However if you have for example `Last-Modified` header, then browser does not need `expires`  header to cache the content and to know when it has expired.
2. don't know
3. `expires` header is **not required** to cache the page and it's actually meant for **dynamic content** when you know the possible expiration date (for example if it's daily generated graph). there are many ways for a document to expire. For example if the document `Last-Modified` header is specified and correct and content length is known then  browsers could cache the page and next time can use `If-Modified-Since` header which will result `304 Not Modified`, so the browser can show cached content. So if Last-Modified is there don't worry - the browser will always show fresh version (with rare exceptions)